# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is Open in c# using Ms access database

Tags: c#

```
 private void txtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                 conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from tblMember where [ID] ='" + txtID.Text + "'", conn);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                }
                conn.Close();
                if (count != 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find Record", "CANT FIND", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }
                else if (count >= 1)
                {

                    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from tblMember where [ID] ='" + txtID.Text + "'", conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader2.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader2.Read();
                        txtFirstName.Text = reader2[1].ToString();
                        txtLastName.Text = reader2[2].ToString();
                        dtpdob.Text = reader2[3].ToString();
                        txtContactNum.Text = reader2[4].ToString();
                        txtContact2.Text = reader2[5].ToString();
                        cboGender.Text = reader2[6].ToString();
                        txtEmailAddress.Text = reader2[7].ToString();
                        txtOccupation.Text = reader2[8].ToString();
                        txtAddress.Text = reader2[9].ToString();
                        cboSubcription.Text = reader2[10].ToString();
                        txtAmount.Text = reader2[11].ToString();
                        txtAmountStat.Text = reader2[12].ToString();
                        txtPendingAmount.Text = reader2[13].ToString();
                        dtpStartDate.Text = reader2[14].ToString();
                        dtpEndDate.Text = reader2[15].ToString();
                        cboTrainer.Text = reader2[16].ToString();
                        cboFacility.Text = reader2[17].ToString();


                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception errrr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(errrr.Message);
            }
            finally {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); }

            }


        }
```

Comment: The `OleDbCommand` & `OleDbDataReader` should be inside `using()` blocks as they are disposable.

Comment: Open once, close once is the best approach, you don't need to open the connection for every query.

Comment: @AlexK. Also there is no need to execute a query and loop to count the records and the reexecute the same query to do your tasks.

Comment: The fact that the code is fired on each keypress isnt helping